# Not able to select a Font file from Windows Fonts folder using OpenFileDialog

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to use the .NET Windows Form OpenFileDialog control to select a font file (not a font as you would with the FontDialog), but the dialog will not allow a mouse click to select a file in the C:\WINDOWS\Font directory.

Any ideas for choosing a font file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fonts folder is customised. In order to make it behave like a normal folder - and allow a font file to be selected from it - you need to remove the ReadOnly and System attributes with `attrib -s -r fonts`. (This is for Windows XP/2003, I can't say for Vista/7)

Comment: This works. Thanks

But, as and when user browses how do you keep track of the selected folder?

There is no event or value to check. 

I can use the above solution only in case if i set fonts as InitialDirectory.